# Работа с классом из другого скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, имею класс

```
public class Perts : MonoBehaviour
{
[System.Serializable]
public class Pert
{
    public float Count;
    public float Shop;
    public float Click;
    public int LevelScore;
}

public Pert PertClass;

// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start()
{
    PertClass = new Pert
    {
        Count = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score"),
        Shop = ShopSecond()
    };
}
}
```

В другом скрипте

```
public class AppPaused : MonoBehaviour
{
private Perts Perts;
private void Start()
{
    Perts = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Perts>();
}

private void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
{
    Perts.PertClass.Count += Convert.ToInt64(......);
}
}
```

На последнюю строчку (perts.PertClass.Count += ....) выдаёт ошибку  Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Смотрел в официальном уроке Unity [Тык](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/classes), там делают как и я

Comment: Ничего не понятно, что за `Perts`, что за `Pert`? Приведите **полный** код в вопрос, а не какие-то отрывки.

Comment: Perts это название скрипта где лежит класс Pert

Comment: Приведите полный код, называть так классы - очень плохая тенденция.

Comment: Хорошо, я поменял код

Comment: Самое очевидное: а компонент `Perts` точно добавлен к объекту с **именем** `Main Camera`?

Comment: Да, точно, даже проверил только что

Comment: Может стоит назвать в классе AppPaused получаемый скрипт Perts как - то по другому, а не так же. Чисто предположение (да и действительно, лучше не называть получаемую переменную скрипта таким же именем, чтобы не запутаться)

Comment: Нет, не помогло

Comment: на null проверьте, что именно у вас не инициализировано, perts или pertclass

Comment: Сходу найти информацию найти не могу, но вероятнее всего событие получения фокуса происходит **ДО** Start()

Comment: Да, [OnApplicationFocus вызывается первым делом при старте приложения](https://answers.unity.com/questions/496290/can-somebody-explain-the-onapplicationpausefocus-s.html), @АлександрДаниловский спасибо за наводку, никогда бы не подумал, что юнити так работает.

Comment: Да, пришлось делать GetComponent в OnApplicationFocus

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский оформите ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Метод`OnApplicationFocus` вызывается раньше, чем `Start`.

Поэтому код

`Perts.PertClass.Count += Convert.ToInt64(......);`

вызывает ошибку **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**, поскольку переменная `Perts` еще не инициализирована и не содержит ссылки на компонент типа `Perts`.